# Unresponsive Eclipse neon.3, RHEL7 w/ oracle_jre_8 in virtualbox

Tags: eclipse, rhel7

Running Eclipse neon.3 in a RHEL7 virtualbox VM, with 8GB total RAM.  On occasion, Eclipse becomes completely unresponsive and the OS system monitor shows the CPU cores taking turns to go to 100%.

eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.201.v20161025-1711.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.401.v20161122-1740
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

jvisualvm shows that the big consumer is

```
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main()
```

I watch as the Total Time goes up 1000 ms every second.  Looks like a busy loop in what looks like the gtk_OS hooks.

The RAM profile for eclipse looks like the Himalayas, so clearly a memory leak.

Anyone notice this behaviour and know what to do about it?

Thanks,
Robin

p.s. very temporary screen grab https://img42.com/0USxM
p.p.s. doanloadable image of jvisualvm here, https://expirebox.com/download/932e3dcaf6a83022d37c567713f2023b.html

Comment: Left to its own devices, eclipse came back to life.  The heap graph still looks like a saw blade and it seems the gc recovery of memory is never complete...memory leak is obvious.  I'll chalk this up to bad memory management in some plugin or in eclipse itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What I know is that the problem completely disappears after turning off +UseG1GC ." 
according to:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1082145/

I had the same problem which disappeared after I updated eclipse to oxygen version.